# why am i getting this cloudflare error on replit?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, cloudflare, replit

I am getting this cloudflare error

[image]

Things I have tried :

1.) running `kill 1` in shell

2.) regenerating token

3.) created a new application on discord developer portal

but it didn't work

also, I am using uptimerobot to keep my bot running

Comment: Replit isn't made to host Discord bots & abusing their platform for it will give you dozens of issues like this one. Get an actual VPS.

Comment: See [more info about Replit being rate limited](https://ask.replit.com/t/discord-ratelimit/3522?u=not-ethan)